# Get column type from materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to get the column type of a materialized view.
I am trying with:

```
select * from user_tab_columns
```

and with:

```
select * from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
```

but I don't have how to filter ONLY the materialized views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be

```
select col.*
  from user_tab_columns col
 where col.table_name in (select mv.mview_name
                            from user_mviews mv)
```

If you wanted to query `all_tab_columns` rather than `user_tab_columns`, you'd want to use `all_mviews` and include the owner as well

```
select col.*
  from all_tab_columns col
 where (col.owner, col.table_name) in (select mv.owner, mv.mview_name
                                         from all_mviews mv)
```